# Binding forms at multiple different mount points with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, flux, redux, redux-form

As I understand from the react-form documentation, you normally put a `form` reducer at the root of your reducer tree, and redux-form will put each form's state inside this `form` key, based on the form's name.

However this will result in a strange structure, whereby the form data for a certain tree is under the form key, and not with the other state data related to it. In this example, the app stores a list of possible account types from the server, which logically should be grouped with the signup form itself. However with redux-form they'll be in completely different subtrees:

```
            signup          
           /
       forms
      /    \
     /      login
    /
 root
     \      login--signinMethods
      \    /
       header
           \
            signup--accountTypes
```

I'd much rather a more organised tree like this:

```
             form          
            /
       signup
      /     \
     /       accountTypes
    /
 root
     \      signinMethods
      \    /
       login
           \
            form
```

Is this possible with redux-form, or any other redux library?

Comment: I am curious what benefit you see this resulting in (splitting up redux-form's state tree)? Personally, I think keeping a `form` tree at the root level to house all form(s) data makes the most sense (as redux-form does out of the box). I suppose you could make use of the formReducer provided and roll your own custom reducers deep down in various places in your state tree (as you suggested). At that point, I feel like you might be fighting your tools (and reinventing wheels) purely out of preference rather than actual merit.

Comment: Yes that would be fighting with the tools and I won't do it if it requires a heap of effort. In this situation though, each form probably has a `<select>` element inside them, and the possible values are populated from redux state (accountTypes and signinMethods in this example). To me, the form data, and the `<select>` options used in these forms should be in the same branch of the tree instead of completely different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [reduxMountPoint](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/api/reduxForm?_k=z4shh6) option:

> The use of this property is highly discouraged, but if you absolutely
>   need to mount your redux-form reducer at somewhere other than form in
>   your Redux state, you will need to specify the key you mounted it
>   under with this property. Defaults to 'form'.

Comment: afaik that still mounts all the forms under one single key, just a different one from just 'form'

Comment: As far as I know you can set reduxMountPoint for every form you use thus making them unique.

Comment: Oh hey you're right! I thought it was a global setting. The next problem is finding out why it's 'highly discouraged'

Comment: To be honest I really don't know. Doesn't look as a hack after looking in the source.

Comment: In redux-form 6, the reduxMountPoint option has been replaced with [getFormState](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-getformstate-function-optional-), and it's gone from "highly discouraged" to "rarely needed." As I understand it, it's not discouraged in the sense that it's a hack or deprecated, but it's rarely needed and can easily complicate your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

It is built the way it is (one reducer handles all forms) to not require adding a new reducer every time you want a new form. You just add the reducer once and forget about it for the most part.